# Add asterisk to Label in model

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following in my view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.StationName)
```

But would like to include an asterisk for each required field. If I change the display name in my model definition it then adds an asterisk to the index view too. How would I do this?

Comment: do you mean *asterisk? [Here's Asterix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix_(character))

Comment: In case you didn't, use this:
http://www.rmo.nl/beeld/tentoonstellingen/Asterix2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a heuristic (I can't give you exact code because I don't have it here):

1. Create a css class that includes appending an asterisk to the content of the tag to which the class is applied.  I believe this is the `content-after` keyword; not sure though.
2. Write a javascript or (my recommendation) jQuery script to run when the page reaches the ready state, to go through all your `label` tags.
3. If the `label` tag refers to an `input` tag that has the required field validation attribute on it (again, don't have the name in front of me), apply the css class created in step 1 to the label.

Answer (score 1):

try doing this :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.StationName)*
```

It will work :)

Comment: if you have any problems and reasons why this doesnt solve your problem .. ask and i shall help

Comment: You even do not need to use DisplayFor. LabelFor also works fine. But, it is in black and we need to use a CSS tag to turn it red!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, ended up doing this on document ready:

```
var lbl;
$('input[data-val-required]').each(function () {
    lbl = $(this).siblings('label');
    $(lbl).html($(lbl).html() + ' *');
});
```

My labels are siblings of the input, but of course it could be modified to work if the labels lies within a parent's sibling as well.